# Remove grid lines(vertical and horizontal) from a handwritten scanned image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I tried to remove the grid lines from the image using hough lines approach,but i am unable to generalize for all images.

My input image :[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI9Rg.jpg)

Output image:[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPbap.jpg)

I want my output image to look like this:
[expected output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZahR.jpg)

Comment: Have you seen [opencv tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html) ?

Comment: a simple global threshold would remove those lines. morphological opening is also a solution. but first I'd try to tweak your scanner parameters for better input images. resolution is also very poor and jpeg compression kills the rest...

Comment: I have tried many different methods to remove lines in the image,but it was working only on one set of images.Every method(for ex:thresholding,houghlines,erode,dilate) has its own parameters which has to be changed accoding to the quality of the input image which doesnt work on any other images.I am actually working on scanned images(different quality) for ICR extraction in which the grid removal step is mandatory for better results. Can someone help me to suggest a method which can work on all types of scanned images.@DmitriiZ @Piglet

Comment: someone who can help me on this